# How can I call my as. class file from another frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I have a code set up in an external as. class file this class file allows for a couple mouse features such as color transformations using swatches. Now the code works well but it only seems to work in frame 1. I want to move all my artwork from frame 1 into frame 4 while loading the as. class file to accompany my features in frame 4. So basically I am just trying to move everything from frame 1 to frame 4. HOW IS THIS DONE ? I tried going to publish settings and changing the eport classes option to frame 4 but no success. Heres my code which is in an external as. file.

```
package code
{
    /*****************************************
     * DrawingSample4 :
     * Demonstrates dynamic color transformations.
     * -------------------
     * See 4_color.fla
     ****************************************/

    import fl.events.SliderEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;



    public class Drawing5 extends MovieClip
    {
        //*************************
        // Properties:

        public var activeSwatch:MovieClip;

        // Color offsets
        public var c1:Number = 0;   // R
        public var c2:Number = 51;  // G
        public var c3:Number = 51;  // B

        //*************************
        // Constructor:

        public function Drawing5()
        {


            // Respond to mouse events
            swatch1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
            swatch2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
            swatch3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
            swatch4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
            swatch5_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
            swatch6_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
            apply_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler,false,0,true);
            previewBox_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragPressHandler);

            // Respond to drag events
            red_slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG,sliderHandler);
            red_slider.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,sliderHandler);
            green_slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG,sliderHandler);
            green_slider.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,sliderHandler);
            blue_slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG,sliderHandler);
            blue_slider.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,sliderHandler);

            // Respond to textfield events
            hexc1_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeHexHandler);
            hexc2_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeHexHandler);
            hexc3_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeHexHandler);
            c1_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeRGBHandler);
            c2_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeRGBHandler);
            c3_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,changeRGBHandler);

            // Draw a frame later
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,draw);


        }





        //*************************
        // Initialization:

        protected function draw(event:Event):void
        {




            // Set color transformations
            swatch1_btn.chipfill.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,127,0,97);
            swatch2_btn.chipfill.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,130,0,0);
            swatch3_btn.chipfill.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,10,106,0);
            swatch4_btn.chipfill.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,0,51,51);
            swatch5_btn.chipfill.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,0,51,102)
            swatch6_btn.chipfill.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,127,127,127);
            previewBox_btn.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,c1,c2,c3);

            // Handle listeners...
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,draw);
        }

        //*************************
        // Event Handling:

        protected function dragPressHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            activeSwatch = new Swatch();
            activeSwatch.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,c1,c2,c3);
            activeSwatch.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dragReleaseHandler);          
            activeSwatch.startDrag(true);
            addChild(activeSwatch);
        }

        protected function dragReleaseHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
        {
            if( activeSwatch.hitTestObject(car) ){
                car.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,c1,c2,c3);
            }
            activeSwatch.stopDrag();
            activeSwatch.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dragReleaseHandler);           
            removeChild(activeSwatch);
        }

        protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            car.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,c1,c2,c3);
        }

        protected function changeRGBHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            c1 = Number(c1_txt.text);
            c2 = Number(c2_txt.text);
            c3 = Number(c3_txt.text);

            if(!(c1>=0)){
                c1 = 0;
            }
            if(!(c2>=0)){
                c2 = 0;
            }
            if(!(c3>=0)){
                c3 = 0;
            }
            hexc1_txt.text = c1.toString(16);
            hexc2_txt.text = c2.toString(16);
            hexc3_txt.text = c3.toString(16);

            updateSliders();
        }

        protected function changeHexHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            c1 = parseInt("0x"+hexc1_txt.text);
            c2 = parseInt("0x"+hexc2_txt.text);
            c3 = parseInt("0x"+hexc3_txt.text);

            if(!(c1>=0)){
                c1 = 0;
            }
            if(!(c2>=0)){
                c2 = 0;
            }
            if(!(c3>=0)){
                c3 = 0;
            }
            c1_txt.text = c1.toString();
            c2_txt.text = c2.toString();
            c3_txt.text = c3.toString();

            updateSliders();
        }

        protected function sliderHandler( event:SliderEvent ):void
        {
            switch( event.target )
            {
                case red_slider:

                    c1 = red_slider.value;
                    break;

                case green_slider:

                    c2 = green_slider.value;
                    break;

                case blue_slider:

                    c3 = blue_slider.value;
                    break;
            }
            updateFields();
        }

        protected function swatchHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            switch( event.target.parent )
            {
                case swatch1_btn:

                    c1 = 127;
                    c2 = 0;
                    c3 = 97;
                    break;

                case swatch2_btn:

                    c1 = 130;
                    c2 = 0;
                    c3 = 0;
                    break;

                case swatch3_btn:

                    c1 = 10;
                    c2 = 106;
                    c3 = 0;
                    break;

                case swatch4_btn:

                    c1 = 0;
                    c2 = 51;
                    c3 = 51;
                    break;

                case swatch5_btn:

                    c1 = 0;
                    c2 = 51;
                    c3 = 102;
                    break;

                case swatch6_btn:

                    c1 = 127;
                    c2 = 127;
                    c3 = 127;
                    break;
            }
            updateFields();
            updateSliders();
        }

        //*************************
        // Utils:

        protected function updateFields():void
        {
            hexc1_txt.text = c1.toString(16);
            hexc2_txt.text = c2.toString(16);
            hexc3_txt.text = c3.toString(16);

            c1_txt.text = c1.toString();
            c2_txt.text = c2.toString();
            c3_txt.text = c3.toString();

            previewBox_btn.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,c1,c2,c3);
        }

        protected function updateSliders():void
        {
            red_slider.value = c1;
            green_slider.value = c2;
            blue_slider.value = c3;

            previewBox_btn.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform(0,0,0,1,c1,c2,c3);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: how are you "loading" or calling this code currently?

Comment: im loading it using an external file thats linked thru the properties tab under publish.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is when you load/call this class it is looking for objects on the stage and if they are not there it will throw errors. So you shouldn't call it until it is on the same frame as the items it is looking for. So if all of your items it is looking for are on frame 4, that is where you should call it.

So go to frame 4 and add this code:

```
var myDrawings5 = new Drawing5();
```

Another option is moving the code currently in the constructor function into a new public function called init().  Then you can load the class whenever you want but you don't call the init() until the items are on the stage.

```
public function Drawing5(){
  // now emtpy
}

public function init(){
  // move code from Drawing5() here
}
```

Then load it and call it where needed

```
var myDrawings5 = new Drawing5();
myDrawings5.init();
```

Comment: This didnt seem to work I tried the first option of just placing the code "var myDrawings5 = new Drawing5();" on frame 4 in my actions layer but no success. Now I already have this external class file working for my objects on stage in frame1 it works fine. but then when I try to move all my objects to frame 4 the as. class file doesnt seem to load from frame 4 and my buttons and mouse events loose functionality. Im just trying to bring everything from frame 1 to frame 4 and delete everything from frame 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you were using Drawing5 as your document class before.  Now you want to run it stand alone in frame 4.  To do this, you will need to give the Drawing5 class a reference to your swfs stage so it knows where to find all of those objects now.

```
var d5:Drawing5 = new Drawing5(this);
```

then add a property to Drawing5 class called _container (or something)

```
private var _container:MovieClip;
```

then in your Drawing 5 constructor, change it to accommodate the new var and set the container

```
public function Drawing5(container:MovieClip){
    _container = container;
}
```

Then in Drawing5, change ALL calls that reference an object like a list or button to include the container in the path like this:

```
// Respond to mouse events
_container.swatch1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,swatchHandler,false,0,false);
```

I hope I understood your problem correctly and this helps.